# Rails nested form for has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, nested-forms

I'm new to rails and trying to make an app. I am almost done implementing the user sign up form and I'm only left with one part that I'm stumped with. The user should be able to choose the languages that they speak, followed by their level of fluency for that language.

I have three models, the `user` model, the `language` model, and the `fluency` model which is my join table. As of now, it appears that I am successfully created a checkbox of (pre-populated and fixed) languages and I am able to create a new user with the associated record for fluency, but the fluency level is nil. The user should be able to indicate their fluency level for each checkboxes language through a fixed range of integers.

How should I go about setting the fluency level, and would I need to update the `new` method or any method in the controllers? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! I will also include some relevant code below.

**My models**

```rb
# user model
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fluencies
  has_many :languages, through: :fluencies
end

# language model
class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fluencies
  has_many :users, through: :fluencies
end

# fluency model
class Fluency < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :language
end
```

**My current user sign up form checkbox**

```
<%= form.label :language, 'Languages spoken' %>
  <%= form.collection_check_boxes(:language_ids, Language.all, :id, :lang) do |b| %>
    <%= b.label class:"label-checkbox" do%> 
    <%=b.check_box + b.text%> 
  <%end%> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is what you're looking for. Google for it to implement.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Emu, I did try implementing it but it didn't turn out correctly. It seems like all I can find online is creating two new entities for both models. I'm still trying!

Comment: You need to totally restructure your form so you have an option to add a language where the user uses a collection select for the language and chooses the relevant fluency , as already mentioned, accepts_nested_attributes_for will help you with this but get the form looking right first, draw it up with a piece of paper and a pen.  This is an old railscast but demos what you need to do, the syntax has changed http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=asciicast